# remove or change at command bcc setting

Tags: debian, email, at

When I run a command with `at` on my Debian server, it is correctly sending the email to my user which I have forwarded to my gmail address, but it's also adding a BCC to `drew@sokar` (my.username@hostname). How can I remove the BCC ? I don't need the email twice (it's generating a delivery failed response). Note that I am looking for a permanent solution to removing the BCC, not a temporary one that I have to issue every time I run `at`.

```
drew@sokar:~$ at now
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
at> echo testing
at> <EOT>
```

Will send the following email

```
Bcc: drew@sokar
Return-Path: <druciferre@gmail.com>
Received: from sokar (XXX-XX-XXX-XXX-XXX.XXXXXX.XXX.XX.com. [XX.XXX.XXX.XXX])
    by smtp.gmail.com with ESMTPSA id xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.x.2016.08.18.19.12.44
    for <drew@sokar>
    (version=TLS1 cipher=AES128-SHA bits=128/128);
    Thu, 18 Aug 2016 19:12:45 -0700 (PDT)
Message-ID: <xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.xxxxx.xxxx@mx.google.com>
Received: by sokar (sSMTP sendmail emulation); Thu, 18 Aug 2016 22:12:43 -0400
From: "Drew" <druciferre@gmail.com>
Date: Thu, 18 Aug 2016 22:12:43 -0400
Subject: Output from your job       13
To: drew

testing
```

**/etc/aliases**

```
drew@sokar:~$ cat /etc/aliases
# /etc/aliases
mailer-daemon: postmaster
postmaster: root
nobody: root
hostmaster: root
usenet: root
news: root
webmaster: drew
www: root
ftp: root
abuse: root
noc: root
security: root
root: drew
```

**/etc/mail.rc**

```
drew@sokar:~$ cat /etc/mail.rc
set ask askcc append dot save crt
ignore Received Message-Id Resent-Message-Id Status Mail-From Return-Path Via Delivered-To
```

Comment: Please add to the post package handling email, `/etc/aliases` content, and `grep root /etc/nail.rc`

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro, sorry for the delay. I'd kind of forgotten about this because I haven't used the command on this server in a while. I've updated the post with the information.

Comment: has someone found a solution to this problem?

Comment: @JohnJ, I have not.